# Some basic question in R writing a R-script for a regression example

Tags: r

First of all I want to point out that I'm not very familiar with R, so sorry if one of the following questions is clear.

My motivation is to write a simple R-script, which should contain:

1. import data
2. do regression of form $ Y=aX+bZ+intercept$
3. some calculations
4. ouput

now here are my questions:

1. This is a very general question: If I wrote the R script, then I have to load it with source(name.R), right? Must be there an additional command to execute the script?
2. Suppose I did my regression with `lm`, like `fit<-lm(Y~X+Z,data=database)` this gives a nice ouput. What I really want is to save the coefficients of the model in a vector. How can I do this? Here would it be a 3-dimensional vector `(intercept, a, b)`. **EDIT** I've tried `coefficient<-coefficient(fit)`. This does not work! `coefficient` is not a numerical vector. There are also the name, i.e. intercept and the value below for the first element of it.
3. If I want to print out the coefficients and some calculations at the very end of the script, how do I do this? Just write `print(....)`?

I'm very thankful for your help and Hopefully I considered all rules and conventions in this forum, since this is my first question. If not, I'm very sorry.

Comment: your question is rather about R programming than about statistics. I think it would fit better to stackoverflow.

Comment: when `source (name.R)` will look for the file name stored in variable `name.R` and try to source that file. If `"name.R"` is the actual file name, you need to use `source ("name.R")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I wrote the R script, then I have to load it with source(name.R), right? Must be there an additional command to execute the script?

Not if your script directly invokes the commands

For instance if name.R contains

```
a <- 1:10
plot(a, a^2, t="l")
```

Then source("name.R") will directly generate a plot

However, if name.R contains

```
myfunction <- function()
   {
   a <- 1:10
   plot(a, a^2, t="l")
   }
```

Then sourcing it will only load the function. You will then have to invoke `myfunction()` to get the plot.

> Suppose I did my regression with lm, like fit<-lm(Y~X+Z,data=database) this gives a nice ouput. What I really want is to save the coefficients of the model in a vector. How can I do this? Here would it be a 3-dimensional vector (intercept, a, b)
>   If I want to print out the coefficients and some calculations at the very end of the script, how do I do this? Just write print(....)?

```
 print(coef(fit))
```

will give you what you need (you can store them in an array with `model.coef <- coef(fit)`)

Also, it can be interesting to run

```
 summary(fit)
```

See `?coef` and `?summary` for more info

Comment: @ nico: Thanks for your answer! I will test it and accept it if everything works fine. Just one more question: Why do one use definitions like : model.coef? What does the "." stand for?

Comment: @ nico: `model.coef<-coef((fit))` does not work. I just want to the numerical values in this vector, not the name and vector. If I select the first element of model.coef, it returns the name: Intercept and below it's value! I really want a vector like (0.023,982,-32)

Comment: @math: You can convert it to a numeric array with `as.numeric(coef(fit))`. Anyway those are just the column names, they shouldn't interfere with further manipulation (generally).

Comment: @math: great! alternatively you can also use `as.vector(coef(fit))`

Comment: Have you seen my question in the first comment about writting everything with this "."? It would be great, if you also could quickly explain in a comment, why one do this in R

Comment: @math: also, to answer your first comment, the `.` does not stand for anything special, in R it is usually used in place of a space. You could as well use `model_coef` or `modelCoef` etc. as variable names

Comment: @ nico: Great! I'm fully satisfied. Thx!